# iOS: Calculating most occurring color in CVPixelBufferRef

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing, colors

I am wondering how I can find the "most occurring" color from a CVPixelBufferRef in iOS.
With this I do not necessarily mean a code sample, but just the technology behind it.

My first thought would just be: add all the colors, devide them. This will get you an avarage. But, my guess, that will always turn out to be something ugly brown-ish.

Other thought: counting the most occurrances of a certain color. But that would give me the problem: 255,0,**135** and 255,0,**134** would not be the same color, although everybody agrees it is pink. Maybe this, but in 'steps' of 50 or something, and in the end get the 'middle' of that 50 ? So i.e.: the number 153 would be in the range 150-200 and thus 175 ?

It should give me a RGB color (or whatever) back, but it should have the same 'feel' as the image..

**Note:** it's not a problem if it is complicated or whatever, I just want it to be good. Just no idea where to start. :)

**Update:** I am now using the code below, and it is working surprisingly well, for code this easy:

```
for(int i = 0; i < bufferSize; i += 4) {
    int b = myPixelBuf[i];
    int g = myPixelBuf[i+1];
    int r = myPixelBuf[i+2];

    float th, br;
    UIColor *color = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:( r / 255.0f) green:( g / 255.0f ) blue:( b / 255.0f ) alpha:1.0f];
    [color getHue:&th saturation:nil brightness:&br alpha:nil];

    int hueInt = floor(th / 0.05f);
    hueInt += 0.5;
    [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:hueInt]];
}
```

In the end I just get the most-occuring hue from the array, and multiply it with 0.05 again to get a "normal" hue value for iOS ranging from 0...1.
The 0.05 factor is just a guess at this moment. Seems to work out pretty well, but I am going to play a little with that factor.

Comment: Counting would be the way to go, I suppose. But RGB color space is (as you pointed out) not very suitable for this purpose. Try to convert your colors to something better fitting like HSV (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV).

Comment: @cli_hlt  Thanks. What's your opinion on my update ?

Comment: Looks reasonable (however, adding 0.5 to an int won't do any good - I think you meant something like *int hueInt = (int)floor((th/0.05)+0.5)*). You should also take into account the saturation and brightness (in order to distinguish black and white) as well as consider bucketing hue values as you require (i.e. range 0-x are red, x-y yellow and so on).

Comment: @cli_hlt Oh yea, nice catch. Should be a float :-) And thanks for the input! Distinguishing black and white was my second todo, but not really relevant for the more complicated hue (coloring) aspect. Thanks!